# java.sql.SQLException: No database selected with MySQL datasource in JBoss

Tags: mysql, jboss, datasource

I have a JBoss EAP 7.3 server and I have created a MySQL datasource

[image: datasource]

When my app tries to execute a query (just a simple select statement), it throws `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected`

According to the datasource setting I have already specified the database name in the URL.It should have selected the database for me.

Did I missed anything or any config I can look into?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Wildfly application server with MySQL. The solution is to add a Connection property like this: databaseName=test